# Can't compile after upgrade: Failed to find integrator bundle for class NSTextFinder

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, osx-lion, ibtool

I just upgraded to Lion and the latest build of monotouch and now I received the following when trying to build any project - even just an empty project from the templates.

Has anyone ever seen this before?
It doesn't look like I need to do anything different after upgrading to lion, at least not from the documentation. Am I missing something?

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
Building: DUmmyTest1 (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)

Performing main compilation...
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs /noconfig "/out:/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/DUmmyTest1.exe" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:+ /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG"  /t:exe "/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/Main.cs" "/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/AppDelegate.cs" "/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/RootViewController.cs" "/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/RootViewController.designer.cs" "/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/DetailViewController.cs" "/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/DetailViewController.designer.cs" 
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)

/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/RootViewController.cs(53,44): warning CS0414: The private field `DUmmyTest1.RootViewController.DataSource.controller' is assigned but its value is never used



Compiling interface definitions
/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text "/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/RootViewController.xib" --compile "/DevTests/DUmmyTest1/DUmmyTest1/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/DUmmyTest1.app/RootViewController.nib" --sdk "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk"
2011-11-01 16:13:29.616 ibtoold[618:e07] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-1938/Framework/WidgetIntegration/IBIntegratorManager.m:278
Details:  Failed to find integrator bundle for class NSTextFinder
Object:   <IBIntegratorManager: 0x400b778e0>
Method:   -registerIntegrator:remainingIntegratorsBySuperclass:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a1a0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010085ebd4 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010085eaa4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000100021b42 -[IBIntegratorManager registerIntegrator:remainingIntegratorsBySuperclass:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  3  0x0000000100021c69 -[IBIntegratorManager registerIntegrator:remainingIntegratorsBySuperclass:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4  0x0000000100021804 -[IBIntegratorManager registerIntegrators:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x00000001000213b4 -[IBIntegratorManager loadAllIntegrators] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x00000001000210cc -[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin init] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7  0x0000000100020f91 +[IBInterfaceBuilderPlugin ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8  0x000000010047eb7c _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x000000010047e38c IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
 10  0x0000000100003e58 (in ibtoold)
 11  0x0000000100001a94 (in ibtoold)
ibtool exited with code 134
Build complete -- 1 error, 1 warning

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 1 warning
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need to install the version of XCode built for Lion after you upgrade (hopefully you haven't done this already).

Comment: `ibtool` is a tool shipped with Xcode, not MonoTouch, so it does looks like an installation issue. Make sure you install Xcode 4.2 for Lion (not 4.1, not 4.2 for Snow Leopard)

Comment: Yep. I thought I had, but I had not.

Comment: Excellent. Would you mind marking this as the answer to your question so that others will see it worked for you?